# Disable CORS on Flutter

Tags: flutter, http, dart, web, cors

even though there are a few post/questions on CORS issues with Flutter I'm still unable to fix it with the solutions available, which mostly involving fixing it on the server-side. In my case, I don't have access to the server/API. Additionally, it's has been very hard to ask the third party to change their services, since while testing with other frameworks/languages such as Python and VBA there were no issues getting data from the API as well as with INSOMNIA testing.

So, my thinking is that for some reason flutter is triggering CORS, is there to "disable" it, on the request?

The error I'm getting is:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://yyy.ytr.com.xx/xxx/xxx/xx/zzzzz'
> from origin 'http://localhost:56659' has been blocked by CORS policy:
> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource.

If I disable CORS locally it works, but obviously, it fails when deployed.

Here's how I'm currently doing my request in Flutter.

```
 else {
  final response = await http.post(Uri.parse(API),
      body: json.encode({
        "key": Key,
        "user": User,
        "pass": Pass,
      }),
      headers: <String, String>{'Content-type': 'application/json'});
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

> In my case, I don't have access to the server/API. Additionally, it's has been very hard to ask the third party to change their services, since while testing with other frameworks/languages such as Python and VBA there were no issues getting data from the API

This third party does not sound very experienced in writing APIs. I would reconsider working with them.

You *cannot* "fix" CORS on your side. Any website running in a browser will be subject to this, whether it's written in Dart or with Flutter or with something else.

If you *have* to access this unprofessional API and you *have* to write a website to do so, you are out of luck. It's impossible.

Your alternatives are:

- Get the API provider to fix their server setup
- Use Flutter to write an actual desktop or mobile application instead of a website

Comment: you're right.. My other option is to write this in Excel with VBA, which gives me the chills. A desktop solution would be the case if the remote deployment wasn't an issue. Any thought on the latter?

Answer (score 2):

I had a lot of troubles about this issues. Some people will tell you to disable cors on chromuim. But it's not a good Practice  because you will not tell to a person who does not understand technology to start his browser without cors. This will make your apps very difficult to use and will let it insecure.

This is why, it's important for you to do it at the 3rd Party API side. You may asked your API provider to add your frontend server IP in his cors white list.

As for my own case, I was using odoo 12 then I found that cors was not easy to rewrite there. That's why I installed a simple NGINX where I allows cors to my Flutter Frontend apps. My Backend apps is on the Port 9092, you may adapt it to any others backend Server. But after it works, don't forget to restrict access on CORS.

This is my related nginx config:

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;
    
    
    upstream odooserver {
     server 127.0.0.1:9092;
    }
    map $http_origin:$host $origin {
        default "";
        http://localhost:9092 $http_origin;
    }
    
    server {
    
         listen 80;
         server_name domainname.com;

         access_log C:/nginx-1.20.1/logs/testing-access.log;
         error_log C:/nginx-1.20.1/logs/testing-error.log;

         proxy_read_timeout 720s;
         proxy_connect_timeout 720s;
         proxy_send_timeout 720s;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
         proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

         location / {
         
         proxy_hide_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin';
         proxy_hide_header  Access-Control-Allow-Origin;
              if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        #
        # Custom headers and headers various browsers *should* be OK with but aren't
        #
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' '*' always;
        #
        # Tell client that this pre-flight info is valid for 20 days
        #
        add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
        add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain; charset=utf-8';
        add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
        return 204;
     }
     if ($request_method = 'POST') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' '*' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' '*' always;
     }
     if ($request_method = 'GET') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' '*' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' '*' always;
     }
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_pass http://odooserver;
         }

         location ~* /web/static/ {
             proxy_cache_valid 200 90m;
             proxy_buffering on;
             expires 864000;
             proxy_pass http://odooserver;
         }

         gzip_types text/css text/less text/plain text/xml application/xml application/json application/javascript;
         gzip on;
     }

  
        


    # another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       8000;
    #    listen       somename:8080;
    #    server_name  somename  alias  another.alias;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}


    # HTTPS server
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       443 ssl;
    #    server_name  localhost;

    #    ssl_certificate      cert.pem;
    #    ssl_certificate_key  cert.key;

    #    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
    #    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    #    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    #    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}
**strong text**
}
```

Answer (score 0):

CORS is a security measure that you shouldn't be disabled. Instead, you should tweak your CORS rules.

If you insist on disabling CORS anyway (because it's only for development), please follow this thread: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/46904

TL;DR you have to disable it in the browser.

Here's a great explanation of CORS: https://gist.github.com/jesperorb/6ca596217c8dfba237744966c2b5ab1e

Comment: tks, @mightybruno. Maybe I didn't express myself correctly. But when I say disable it I meant to no trigger CORS with Flutter. Also, locally I was able to test it disabling, which is not ideal, since once deployed that issue is still there.

Comment: Please have a look at second and third paragraph of my answer. Also, I'd recommend reading the contents of the last link I've posted.

Comment: Tks @mightbruno, I had hopped for JSONP to work, but it seems to work only for GET methods, but not for POST, which is my case.